# Unable to cast double into int

Tags: java

I am experiencing a very weird issue for which I'd be glad to get some help.

I have the following function:

```
private static Object getJavaValue(CellValue cellValue, boolean keepDecimals) {
    switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
        case NUMERIC -> {
            double doubleValue = cellValue.getNumberValue();
            int intValue = (int) doubleValue;
            return keepDecimals ? doubleValue : intValue;
        }
        //other case blocks (not relevant for the question)
    }
    //throw statement (not relevant for the question)
}
```

The input `CellValue cellValue` is an object belonging to the Apache POI library, made to manipulate Excel files.
But I don't think this is really relevant for my question.

So the issue is that I'm calling this function with a `NUMERIC` cell type, so I get the value with `cellValue.getNumberValue()` which returns a `double`.

Then, depending on the boolean `keepDecimals`, I will decide whether I leave the result as `double` or rather I cast it into `int`.

When I call this function with `keepDecimals` false, I see that the variable `intValue` is correctly initialized as an `int`:

[image]

However, as soon as the function return, the value is actually a `Double`:

[image]

What's happening here? Is this related to the fact that I'm returning `Object` (but if that was the case I would have expected `Integer` rather than `Double`, as I'm clearly returning an `int` and not a `double`)?

Note this is not an issue of the IDE, I've tried compiling the code with `mvn clean install` on command line and the unit test fails for the exact same reason.

I'm using Java 17. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a copy-pastable example to reproduce the issue (without need of referencing the Apache POI library which is actually unrelated):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Supplier<Double> supplier = () -> 34.0;
    Object javaValue = getJavaValue(supplier, false);
    System.out.println(javaValue.getClass() + " with value " + javaValue);
}

private static Object getJavaValue(Supplier<Double> supplier, boolean keepDecimals) {
    double nb = supplier.get();
    return keepDecimals ? nb : (int) nb;
}
```

Comment: Will you create a self-contained code example that we can copy/paste and run ourselves to see the behavior you are asking about?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice done, you can find it in the question. It's unrelated to Apache POI as I was suspecting

Comment: Your example has no error.

Comment: @Boann do you mean that the behavior is expected, or do you mean that when you execute that code you get "class java.lang.Integer with value 34"?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I thought you were expecting an exception or something. No, the behavior is expected. The expression `condition ? (double)x : (int)x` will always give a double.

Comment: @Boann thanks for the explanation, I've read the duplicate link and indeed it perfectly answers my question. Thanks for your time